# When analyzing packets with Wireshark, is there a way to know which program is sending which packet?

Tags: wireshark, packet

is there an easy way to know from where the packets come from? Which program?

My pc which is on 192.168.0.100 is continuously sending packets (TCP and SMB) to an unknown host (192.168.1.99) and I can't figure out which program is doing that.

Comment: netstat -abn does the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you might just want to use a software firewall, like [ZoneAlarm](http://www.zonealarm.com/security/en-us/zonealarm-pc-security-free-firewall.htm), it will tell you what apps on a computer are sending where.

Comment: I'm not convinced that I need a firewall to that...

Comment: You don't need one, it is just a simple method for seeing what app is sending info out to which IP address. It will of course only give you basic information, so it all depends on what level of detail you're after.

Answer (score 2):

No, wireshark doesn't have this data. Remember, it's sniffing the wire. If you were on a shared network segment, it would show packets from other machines. Hell, even in an unshared segment it shows packets bound to you from other machines, or broadcasts - wireshark certainly has no way of knowing what processes on the remote machines generated those.

What OS are you using? If it's Windows, netstat or TCPView (from Sysinternals) work. I think netstat is also the command on most Unixes.

Comment: Thanks! I'm on Windowns. I'll try netstat and TCPView and come back with the results.

Comment: Just a note: The processes in on my machine, not remote. But I understand, Wireshark cannot do this trick.

Comment: Microsoft Network Monitor 3.4 can show you both the PID and the name of the process responsible for the traffic.

Comment: Good call, Joe.

Comment: Glad to help...

Comment: I've tried MS Network Monitor and it show me an system process. With ZoneAlarm I figure out that is a printer from another network that doesn't exist anymore. I was wondering how I would discover such thing without help of ZoneAlarm...

Comment: (Note that NetMon obviously can't show you the process responsible for a packet that's not sent from or to the machine running NetMon.)